# How can I create a "Material" ProgressBar without AppCompat?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to replicate the indeterminate ProgressBar seen [here](https://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_8/material_ext_publish/0B0NGgBg38lWWVXBBVF9qR3E4a2s/components-progressactivity-typesofindicators-061101_Linear_Sheet_xhdpi_003.mp4). My first thought was to use the secondary progress attribute to make it so that the two progress bars are "chasing each other, but that doesn't seem to be working.

Progress bar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/transparent" />
        </shape>
    </item>
   <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_red_light" />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_blue_light" />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

and the style:

```
<style name="Widget.ProgressBarHorizontal" parent="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal" />
    <item name="android:indeterminateDrawable">@drawable/progress</item>
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/progress</item>
    <item name="android:indeterminate">true</item>
    <item name="android:indeterminateBehavior">repeat</item>
    <item name="android:indeterminateDuration">1000</item>
    <item name="android:progress">50</item>
    <item name="android:secondaryProgress">30</item>
</style>
```

Thanks!

Comment: At least, post that you got to we could see that's needed to fix.

Comment: But if you look on the video that you posted you can see that first and second lines have different speeds. So, I don't think that you can make this effect using xml only.